# FFMPEG: Cannot record audio when using android_camera on Android mobile device or emulator

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, android, microphone, rtmp

I am attempting to livestream video and audio to my local network from a mobile Android device as a use case for the company I work for.

After searching around, I was able to create a video stream using the following command:

`ffmpeg -f android_camera -i 0 -c:v libx264 -f flv rtmp://$url`

The only issue with this command is in the title, I cannot figure out how to get audio input from the microphone built into the device. I have tried different iterations such as:

**Using android_audio**

`ffmpeg -f android_camera -i 0 -f android_audio -i 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://$url`

**Using mapping**

`ffmpeg -f android_camera -i 0 -f android_audio -i 0 -map 0:v -map 1:v -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://$url`

I feel as though I have hit a wall and am unable to progress. And before it is said, yes I do need to use FFMPEG as the command medium and cannot use a prebuilt project/package as the devices have a program already installed to take FFMPEG commands. Any help on this topic is greatly appreciated.

P.S. If you can also help me figure out how to find the name of an Android device's internal microphone, that would be lovely.

Comment: *Questions about Android devices are off-topic for Super User and should be asked on android.stackexchange.com unless they specifically involve interaction with a computer.*

Comment: Technically this does involve interactions with a computer as a centralized server is used to receive the video streams. I mainly just need the proper command to get said video and audio from the handheld device to the server.

Comment: Where are you running this command? On the android phone, or on the PC "server"? What is the name of the Android audio device? Is it supposed to work this way?

Comment: I am running the command from the android device to the server. I am unsure of the audio device and I do not know which command to run in order to list the devices found on the android device.